# Let $X$ and $y$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with probabilities ...

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables

Let $X$ and $y$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with probabilities

$$P(X=n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
pq^{n-1}, n\geq 1\\ 
0, n<1
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$P(Y=m)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
pq^{m-1}, m\geq 1\\ 
0, m<1
\end{matrix}\right.$$
where $0<p<1$ and $p+q=1$. Evaluate the probabilities of the sum of $X$ and $Y$
$$P(Z=r)=P(X+Y=r).$$

**My solution so far:**

Note that $P(X=n)=f_{X}(n)$ and $P(X=m)=f_{Y}(m)$.

$$P(Z=r) = P(Z=X+Y) =  f_{Z}(z).$$
$$f_{Z}(z) = \sum_{{\left \{ (n,m)|n+m=r \right \}}}P(X=n,Y=m)$$
$$=\sum_{n}P(X=n,Y=z-n)=\sum_{n}f_{X}(n)f_{Y}(z-n)$$
$$=\sum_{n}pq^{n-1}pq^{z-n-1}= p^{2}q^{z-2}\sum_{n}q^{0}= p^{2}q^{z-2}\sum_{n=1}^{r-1}1 = p^{2}q^{z-2}(r-1).$$

EDIT - I believe I got it now.

It seems that the sum diverges to infinity, which is not correct. Is there anything wrong here?

Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You did not consider the cases when $z-n < 1$, of which its pmf gets evaluated to $0$.
- You seems to use two notations, $z$ and $r$ to denote the same thing.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_X(n) f_Y(r-n)&=\sum_{n=1}^{r-1} f_X(n) f_Y(r-n)
\end{align}

which is a finite sum.

Comment: You're right I didn't need the lower case r, just the z is fine. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I don't understand how you got the case when $z - n < 1$. Do you mind explaining further? Thanks!

Comment: $r-n$ is the entry for $f_Y$. we know that for $f_Y$ if the input argument is less than $1$, then it is evaluated to be zero. Hence it suffices to look at the cases when $r-n \ge 1$, which is equivalent to $n \le r-1$.

Comment: Oh riiight. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is bounded because the number of terms is finite. You can only sum from $n=1$ to $n=r-1$, otherwise $Y$ would drop out of the supported range.

Answer (score 1):

...
Greetings, robot friend!

The reason why you are encountering a DOES NOT COMPUTE is that some programmer has mistakenly forgotten to bound one of your loops. The sum cannot go larger than $z-1$ (remember that $n$ is the value of $X$ which can't be larger than $z-1$ since $Z=X+Y.$) So instead you need to take $\sum_{n=1}^{z-1}.$

Comment: *Beep* you *boop* are *beep* correct *gerrkkk*. Thank *smoke* you!!!